# Pass shell-escaped string of arguments to a subcommand in Bourne shell

Tags: shell, escaping, arguments, quotes, sh

Say I have a command I want to run (`cmd`) and a variable containing the arguments I want to pass to the function (something like `--foo 'bar baz' qux`).  Like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
command=cmd
args="--foo 'bar baz' qux"
```

The arguments contain quotes, like the ones shown above, that group together an argument containing a space. I'd then like to run the command:

```
$command $args
```

This, of course, results in running the command with *four* arguments: `--foo`, `'bar`, `baz'`, and `qux`. The alternative I'm used to (i.e., when using `"$@"`) presents a different problem:

```
$command "$args"
```

This executes the command with *one* argument: `--foo 'bar baz' qux`.

How can I run the command with *three* arguments (`--foo`, `bar baz`, and `qux`) as intended?

Comment: Quick bit of pedantry: Modern `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not Bourne. (...and no, POSIX sh is **not** a pure superset of 1970s-era Bourne: For instance, in Bourne -- but not POSIX sh or modern derivatives such as ash, dash, ksh or bash -- `^` is a valid pipe character).

Comment: I see your pedantry, and raise you another bit of pedantry: Solaris 10 is "modern" (came out in the 21st century, and still in production use, though fortunately dwindling by now), and yet its `/bin/sh` is definitely not POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use `eval`:

```
#!/bin/sh

args="--foo 'bar baz' qux"
cmd="python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv'"

eval $cmd $args
```

That way you cause the command line to be interpreted rather than just split according to `IFS`. This gives the output:

```
$ ./args.sh 
['-c', '--foo', 'bar baz', 'qux']
```

So that you can see the args are passed as you wanted.

Comment: No need for Python for that: In bash, `printf %q "$@"` will show your argv in unambiguous form. (And to all those reading -- please, please use eval only if you COMPLETELY trust your inputs, and can't get the desired result any other way; if the variable you're eval'ing might contain anything an untrusted user could create... say, names of files in `/tmp`, using eval is opening yourself to pain, suffering and security holes).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You're right about `eval`, but `printf %q` is a Bashism, and the question is about Bourne Shell.

Comment: Thanks! The inputs are 100% trusted here, so this will work perfectly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in that some of the arguments my script receives are passed on to another script for execution. Use of `eval` is probably okay, and I suppose I could filter for harmful elements just in case, but are there really no alternatives? I tried using `sed` to escape spaces for example, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Haravikk, there's exactly one array available in POSIX sh -- `"$@"`; it's locally scoped (so one can preserve the original form by putting any manipulations inside a function), and can be modified through the use of `set`. So -- sometimes unambiguous manipulation of an argument vector is possible in POSIX sh, but it's all about the details. If the ksh extensions adopted into bash didn't enable things one couldn't do without them, after all, there wouldn't be much point to them existing.

Comment: It's entirely possible to do the equivalent of `printf %q` using only portable `sh` constructs. Here's [my implementation](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/esceval/blob/master/sh/esceval.sh) which uses the almost universally supported substring substitutions (`${foo#bar}`, etc) where possible, and falls back to `sed` when the former is not possible. Sadly, this robustness comes at the cost of some legibility, on account of the possibly-unsupported syntax needing to be wrapped in an `eval`.

Answer (score 8):

Use an array to specify your argument list exactly, without string-splitting (which is what's doing the wrong thing here) getting in your way:

```
args=( --foo "bar baz" qux )
command "${args[@]}"
```

If you need to build your argument list dynamically, you can append to arrays with `+=`:

```
args=( )
while ...; do
   args+=( "$another_argument" )
done
call_your_subprocess "${args[@]}"
```

Note that the use of quotation marks, and `[@]` instead of `[*]`, is essential.

Comment: The OP is asking about Bourne Shell (i.e. `/bin/sh`).  This would be a good solution for `bash`, but I don't believe bourne shell supports arrays, does it?

Comment: Thanks! This might be a reason to switch to bash for this program.

Answer (score 5):

If you can throw away the current positional variables (`$1`...) you can use the following:

```
set -- '--foo' 'bar baz' 'qux'
echo "$#" # Prints "3" (without quotes)
echo "$2" # Prints "bar baz" (without quotes)
command "$@"
```

Just tested it in a `#!/usr/bin/env sh` script, so it works at least in Dash, and should work in any Bourne Shell variant. No [`eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), Python or Bash necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the command in the form:

```
args="--foo 'bar baz' qux"
```

and getting the command as an array in the first place isn't an option, then you'll need to use `eval` to turn it back into an array:

```
$ args="--foo 'bar baz' qux"
$ eval "arr=($args)"
```

But it's important to note that **this is unsafe** if `$args` is being provided by an untrusted source, since it can be used to execute arbitrary commands, e.g. `args='$(rm -rf /)'; eval "arr=($args)"` will cause the above code to run the `rm -rf /` before you've even used `arr`.

Then you can use `"${arr[@]}"` to expand it as arguments to a command:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $0' "${arr[@]}"
--foo
$ bash -c 'echo $1' "${arr[@]}"
bar baz
```

or to run your command:

```
"$command" "${arr[@]}"
```

Note that there are differences between `${arr[*]}`, `${arr[@]}`, `"${arr[*]}"` and `"${arr[@]}"`, and only the last of these does what you want in most cases

Comment: Good advice, but OP is asking about bourne shell.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by changing the `IFS` (the internal field seperator) of the shell (to only contain a newline). Here is how I override commands that use quoted arguments:

```
$ cat ~/.local/bin/make
#!/bin/sh

# THIS IS IMPORTANT! (don't split up quoted strings in arguments)
IFS="
"
exec /usr/bin/make ${@} -j6
```

(`/bin/sh` is `dash`)
It will eat the quotes when replacing the command with `echo`, so will look wrong when "testing"; but the command does get them as intended.

It can be tested by replacing the `exec` line with

```
for arg in $@; do echo $arg; done
```