# Passing arguments to a Python script from a shell variable containing quoted spaces

Tags: python, bash, quotes, spaces

I am calling a python script through a bash wrapper, but I'm having trouble dealing with arguments that contain quoted spaces.

I assemble the arguments to the python script into a bash variable, such as

```
opt="-c start.txt"
opt+="--self 'name Na'"
```

Then call the python script with something like:

```
python test_args.py $opt
```

When printing `sys.argv` in Python, I get

```
['test-args.py', '-c', 'start.txt', '--self', "'name", "Na'"]
```

instead of the expected

```
['test-args.py', '-c', 'start.txt', '--self', 'name Na']
```

I tried using an array when calling the script, such as

```
python test_args.py ${opt[@]}
```

but then I get

```
['test-args.py', "-c start.txt --self 'name Na'"]
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982573/pass-shell-escaped-string-of-arguments-to-a-subcommand-in-bourne-shell) will help (look at the *eval* solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array, but store each argument as a separate element in the array:

```
opt=(-c start.txt)
opt+=(--self 'name Na')

python test_args.py "${opt[@]}"
```

See [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: This is exactly what I came up with in the end, thanks for writing it up!

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) module is for.

> The shlex class makes it easy to write lexical analyzers for simple
>   syntaxes resembling that of the Unix shell. This will often be useful
>   for writing minilanguages, (for example, in run control files for
>   Python applications) or for parsing quoted strings.

Answer (score -1):

Your instinct to embed spaces inside the variable's value was good, but when the value is simply expanded during the command line parsing their special meaning is lost as you saw. You need to expand the variable before the command line to your python script is parsed:

```
set -f
eval python test_args.py $opt
set +f
```

That will expand to:

```
python test_args.py -c start.txt --self 'name Na'
```

Which will then be parsed correctly with the quotes regaining their special meaning.

Edit: I've added set -f/+f (aka -/+o noglob) around the eval to disable file globbing although that wasn't an issue in the OP's example that's not an unheard of issue with eval. (Another, stronger caveat is to never eval user input unless you take extreme care to make sure it won't blow up into something nasty. If you don't control the value being eval-ed, you can't be sure what will happen.)

Comment: Please don't use `eval`, it has a well-deserved reputation for causing bizarre bugs. For example, try this with `opt="-c start.txt --self 'name * Na'"` and try to explain the result.

Comment: I reject your risk assessment in the context of the OP which shows the script controlling the content of the value to be eval-ed, but agree a caveat is called for.

Might have been more helpful though if you'd suggested surrounding the eval with `set -f ... set +f` to disable file globbing. (Which is the problem you're hinting it, of course.)